# AppleScript for Dropbox on External HD

Tags: finder, hard-drive, applescript, mount, dropbox

Disclaimer: I don't know much AppleScript, but I am a bit of a programmer, so you can go a little technical on me.

I am looking for a solution to the issue of putting Dropbox on an external HD.  While they don't advise it, I think that it can be done safely with a couple measures:

1. Run Dropbox when the hard drive is mounted through AppleScript.  This shouldn't be hard because I read that there is `StartOnMount` or I can listen for the hard drive's "folder" in `/Volumes` like [here](http://osquestions.com/osx-ios/8090/how-to-run-applescript-on-disk-mount).
2. Stop Dropbox when the hard drive is ejected, wherein lies the problem.  Is there an event triggered by pushing the eject button that would allow me to run a script before un-mounting?

Either I use the above method or I somehow disable the drive from being unmounted by Mac OS X and mount and un-mount only through AppleScripts (hide it from the Finder's sidebar or, preferably, something better).  Which of those is the easier solution?

Comment: Why applescript?

Comment: Put the Dropbox.app on the drive itself! Than it will be quit by the system:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[CousinCocaine](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/55028/cousincocaine) was correct about putting the Dropbox app on the drive itself.  That prohibits the drive from being ejected without closing Dropbox, except for force ejecting, which I don't plan on doing, and just yanking the cord out, which I hope I don't do (I think that the app might close as a result of the latter).  The easiest way to relocate the app is to just drag and drop it onto the drive and always run it from there.

As for specifying a custom location, [this link](https://www.dropbox.com/en/help/89) shows you how to do it in the Dropbox interface.  Not only does it now look there for the files but it actually moved everything to the new location automatically.  Definitely didn't need AppleScript and I am not entirely sure why the Dropbox team don't promote this solution on their site.

Answer (score 0):

I use to have multiple dropbox instances running at once. I think you can put db  app on the drive and use the same trick I did.

```
HOME=/Volumes/Whereever/you/wanna/go; /Volumes/Whereever/Dropbox.app/Contents/MacOS/Dropbox &
```

One thing. With this method you change your default $HOME into your new path. So Dropbox *will* create a folder called `Dropbox` in that path.

Comment: You can specify a custom location for the Dropbox folder. Don't have to change the HOME variable.

Comment: This way the Dropbox will not default to ~/ when the drive is not there

Comment: Ah. Nice idea!.

Comment: This is the HOME variable in bash, correct?  Is there a way I can keep my home directory as it is now and have Dropbox on the hard drive?

Comment: Using home this way will only change home for dropbox.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks a lot!  I get my hard drive today and will give it a shot, an mark it answered if it works.